# google maps navigation

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to develop an gps application that can navigate to some predermined locations in a database.

I have created a mapview wich is working just fine, I also have a MyLocationOverlay to show my position and I have a ItemzedOverlay to show the locations to which I want to navigate. This is no problem. the problem is the creation of a route from the phones location to a predermined location.

If anyone knows anything I will be happy for your answers!

//

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264851/zooming-on-android-dev-google-maps-becomes-slower for tips.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is launch an intent that tells the OS that you want to launch Google Maps Navigation.

Comment: thx for the tip! But as I live in sweden I am not able to use google maps navigation :( .. yet... maybe I'll just have to wait with this project..